# Powershell query database and store results in a variable

Tags: powershell

I have written a powershell script to query a database to get a list of server names. I then store the results in a variable so I can go through each server to lookup a service by doing something like: `foreach ($server in $servers)`. I have no issue storing the results in a variable but when I do a foreach statement, it doesn't let me retrieve the server name 1 by 1 properly.

If I manually type out the server names like `$servers = (server, server2,server3)` then the `forEach` will work.
What's the proper way of doing this?

Updated:  Below is the script

```
$SQLServer= 'sourceServer'
$Database = 'DatabaseNameHere'
```

Create a SQL Query function

```
Function SQL_Query ($Query) {
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection 
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = 
"Server=$SQLServer;Database=$Database;Integrated Security=True"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand 
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection 
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $Query 
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter 
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd 
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet 
$a=$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet) 
$SqlConnection.Close() 
$DataSet.Tables[0]  
}
```

Use this function

```
$list=SQL_Query "Select ServerName From Server_Inventory Where Status = 'A' "
```

Check returned Server list

```
$list
```

I would like to go through each server and see what servers are installed on each server

```
$output= Foreach ($server in $list) {
$output=Get-DbaSqlService -ComputerName $server | Where-Object 
{$_.ServiceType -in ('SSIS','Agent','Engine','SSRS','FullText')} 
}
$output | Out-GridView -Title "View all SQL Services"
```

Comment: Can we see your powershell script?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't let you retrieve the server names properly? Have you printed `$servers` to check to see if you are in fact storing the results and using the `GetType()` command to check that `$servers` is actually a list?

Comment: added script to original post, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$DataSet.Tables[0]` is an object with the columns from the query as properties. In your case `$list` will be an PowerShell object with property ServerName.

**Solution 1** 
When calling `Get-DbaSqlService -ComputerName $server`, you will pass one the whole object, where you only want to provide the name, when you change this to `Get-DbaSqlService -ComputerName $server.ServerName` you will only pass on the value of the property ServerName.

**Solution 2**
As you only want to explore the Servername property, you could already expand it so `$list` will represent what you expect. Therefore you should add `Select-Object -ExpandProperty ServerName` where you define `$list`.

So

```
$list = SQL_Query "Select ServerName From Server_Inventory Where Status = 'A' "
```

becomes

```
$list = SQL_Query "Select ServerName From Server_Inventory Where Status = 'A' " | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ServerName
```

---

**Addition**
The `$output` variable is overwritten in each loop. The results for each server should be appended to the output variable.

```
$output = @()
Foreach ($server in $list) {
   $output += Get-DbaSqlService -ComputerName $server | Where-Object {$_.ServiceType -in ('SSIS','Agent','Engine','SSRS','FullText')} 
}
$output | Out-GridView -Title "View all SQL Services"
```

Comment: I tried both solutions and both of them only gave me the results of the last server on the list, which is the same as my current script as well. Do i need to pass $server.Servername since $list is already storing by server name like:
Server1  ...next row
Server2 ...next row
Server3

Comment: I misinterpreted the issue, the loop is working, only the last result is stored. I added an (untested) suggestion how to solve that part!

Comment: That's it, i found the issue in my script. I had the $output =@() line but I didn't put a '+' in front of the '=' on line $output += Get-DbaSqlService...